# How to know which text string is selected by user in JavaFX TextArea

Tags: textarea, javafx, selection, highlighting, textselection

I need to allow the user to highlight text (select a range with the mouse), then I want to give them the ability to apply some setting to that text form a drop down right click menu.

I know the latter part. But how do I get which text string is selected from a Text Area in JavafX?

Also, would I be able to apply different styles to different strings?

Comment: I tried this handler, but does not seem to do anything --------------textArea.addEventHandler(MouseDragEvent.MOUSE_DRAG_RELEASED, new EventHandler< MouseDragEvent>(){  

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseDragEvent t) {
                System.out.println("u selected this: "+textArea.getSelectedText()); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        });

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `getSelectedText()` to get the selected text.

The answer to your second question is yes.

The `getSelectedText()` method can be used like I have done here:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextAreaDemo extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        final TextArea textArea = new TextArea("Text Sample");
        textArea.setPrefSize(200, 40);

        textArea.setOnContextMenuRequested(new EventHandler<Event>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event arg0)
            {
                System.out.println("selected text:"
                    + textArea.getSelectedText());
            }
        });

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(textArea);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(vBox, 300, 250));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Once you launch this application, it shows a `TextArea` with some text (`Text Sample`). I selected some part of the text and did a right click. It printed the selected text. Does this fit your requirement?

Comment: Oh my God.. I have no idea why for some reason, I only saw the "getSelectedText()" comment. No code was showing. The above worked!!!! You're are my hero for the day :)

Comment: :) Glad this was of help.

Comment: my last question for the day (since you seem to be online! :D). Would it be possible to apply different font styles to strings in a single text area? I read that it was not possible or at least not straight forward.. (that is my second battle with Javafx). I was thinking of grabbing all characters and assign a style to each... what do you suggest?

Comment: :) Please put this in a separate question. In short, I think this should be doable.

Comment: Ok! just added a question.